# Programmatically Filter Excel Data Using Java

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I am working on a web application, where the user uploads a Excel file with a lot of data, the sheet in workbook is like a table in a DB, where each column corresponds to a data column, based on some input from the user in the UI I need to filter the data obtained form the excel.

How can i do this?

I looked up on 'Reading Excel as Datasource using JDBC', but i am unable to setup an ODBC driver that points to the Excel spreadsheet using the code shown
[here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/UseJDBCODBCbridgetoreadfromExcel.htm). can someone please guide me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the number of filters are more, and data is large, moreover i need to perform this operation frequently, hence looking for a optimizes approach. SQL query on Excel really got my attention, but unable to achieve it for my situation(till now at-least!)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to take a look at the JExcelApi which is made for accessing Excel-Sheets from Java programmatically: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: jexcel is easier to use. But offers less.